# Overflow sort stage buffered data usage

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing

We have a mongoDB 2.6.4 replica set running and are trying to diagnose this behavior.   We are getting the `Runner error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33598393 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes` when we expect that we would not.  The collection has millions of records and has a compound index that includes the key that is being sorted.    As an example

index looks like this

```
{ from: 1, time : -1, otherA : 1, otherB : 1}
```

our find is

```
 find.collection({ from : { $in : ["a", "b"] }, time : { $gte : timestamp }, 
       otherA : {$in:[...]}, otherB : {$in:[...]}})
       .sort( time : -1 )
```

mongoDB parallels (clauses) this query like this:

```
{ from : a }, { time : { $gte : timestamp }, ... }
{ from : b }, { time : { $gte : timestamp }, ... }
```

In the explain each stage reports that scanAndOrder : false,  which implies that the index was used to return the results.  This all seems fine, however the mongoDB client gets the  Runner error: Overflow sort stage buffered data usage error. This seems to imply that the sort was done in memory. Is this because it is doing an in-memory merge sort of the clauses? Or is there some other reason that this error could occur?

Comment: Can you post the full explain for a query?

Comment: maybe mongo can't merge the sorted parallels partial results.  If you query just {from: "a"} and just {from: "b"}, do those work?  One work-around could be to merge manually, outside of mongo.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem of memory overflow.
I am using PHP with MongoDB to manipulate Documents.
When I am accessing a collection which is probably having large set of documents it is throwing an error.
As per the following link, it can sort only upto 32MB data at a time.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Sorted-Documents .

So as per the description given in MongoDocs about sorting,
I sorted the array converted from MongoCursor object with PHP rather than Mongo's sort() method.

Hope it'll help you.
Thanks.